# SQL Server stored procedure - parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that returns a grid result. I'm having some fundamental issues with transferring the `@idCC` parameter to the SQL query as shown. I know the SQL works if I remove the parameter and hard code in a number value. How do I allow the query to read `@idCC` to the query shown?

```
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO

    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_CC_ContactGroupList] 
        (@idCC int)
    AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @ListOfGroups VARCHAR(MAX) =
                (STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(GroupName) 
                        FROM dbo.CC_Groups
                        WHERE IsContactGroup = '1'
                        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, ''));

        DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX) = ('SELECT * 
                                      FROM
                                          (SELECT       
                                               dbo.CC_Contacts.idCC, 
                                               dbo.CC_Groups.GroupName AS gName, 
                                               ''X'' AS IsInGroup
                                           FROM          
                                               dbo.CC_ContactGroups 
                                           INNER JOIN
                                               dbo.CC_Groups ON dbo.CC_ContactGroups.idGroup = dbo.CC_Groups.idGroup 
                                           INNER JOIN
                                               dbo.CC_Contacts ON dbo.CC_ContactGroups.idCC = dbo.CC_Contacts.idCC
                                           WHERE 
                                               dbo.CC_Contacts.idCC = '''+@idCC+''') AS x
                                           PIVOT (MAX(IsInGroup) 
                                               FOR gName IN(' +  @ListOfGroups + ')) as p');

     EXEC(@sql);
END
```

Comment: How is the query string shown if you `PRINT` it?

Comment: replace WHERE dbo.CC_Contacts.idCC = '''+@idCC+'''
with WHERE dbo.CC_Contacts.idCC = + @idCC

Comment: The row looks like: |idCC|GroupName1|GroupName2|GroupName3| with values like |25|Null|X|Null|X|

Comment: is the error solved?

Comment: No, the SQL command is in quotes, you have to escape the quotes in order to read the parameter. I think.

Comment: can you print the @sql and paste here

Comment: SELECT     dbo.CC_Contacts.idCC, dbo.CC_Groups.GroupName AS gName, 'X' AS IsInGroup
FROM          dbo.CC_ContactGroups INNER JOIN
   dbo.CC_Groups ON dbo.CC_ContactGroups.idGroup = dbo.CC_Groups.idGroup INNER JOIN
      dbo.CC_Contacts ON dbo.CC_ContactGroups.idCC = dbo.CC_Contacts.idCC
   WHERE dbo.CC_Contacts.idCC = '25'
 ) AS x
 PIVOT
 (
    MAX(IsInGroup) FOR gName IN([GroupName1],[GroupName2],[GroupName3],[GroupName4],[GroupName5],[GroupName6])
 ) as p' to data type int.

Comment: I changed the @idCC to 25 for the print of the SQL

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135310/discussion-between-chintan-udeshi-and-pigsincorporated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your stored procedure `[dbo].[sp_CC_ContactGroupList]`, replace

```
dbo.CC_Contacts.idCC = '''+@idCC+'''
```

with

```
dbo.CC_Contacts.idCC = '''+cast(@idCC as varchar)+'''
```

Now it will show you `@idCC`

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you.